# List json processing

Tags: json, scala

I have difficulty processing a list a Scala:
Currently I have a list of like this

```
(List(JString(2437), JString(2445), JString(2428), JString(321)), CompactBuffer((4,1)))
```

and I would like after processing, the result will look like below:

```
( (2437, CompactBuffer((4,1))), (2445, CompactBuffer((4,1))), (2428, CompactBuffer((4,1))), (321, CompactBuffer((4,1))) )
```

Can any body help me with this issue? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val pair = (List(JString(2437), JString(2445), JString(2428), JString(321)), 
            CompactBuffer((4,1)))

val result = pair._1.map((_, pair._2))
```

First, `pair._1` gets the list from the tuple. Then, `map` performs the function on each element of the list. The function `(_, pair._2)` puts the given element from the list in a new tuple together with the second part of the `pair` tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I having some errors when trying to apply your solution: value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[(Int, Int)])]. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I see you've now asked this as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005737/error-processing-scala-list.