# JSon-Scala - Parse list

Tags: json, scala, predictionio

I have problem parsing JSon into RDD

{"data":"{\"orderID\":\"3\",\"products\":[{\"productID\":10028,\"category\":\"342\",\"name\":\"Kids Coats\",\"gender\":\"Kids\",\"sport\":\"Basketball\",\"color\":\"Blue\",\"retailPrice\":268.0,\"sellPrice\":268.0,\"sellQuantity\":1,\"taxablePrice\":268.0,\"brand\":\"Inno Fashion\",\"stockQuantity\":999,\"subTotal\":268.0,\"ancesstorCategories\":[\"2426\",\"2454\",\"241\",\"342\",\"24\",\"34\",\"2439\",\"21\",\"3\",\"2\",\"1\",\"2412\",\"2430\",\"2503\"]},{\"productID\":10031,\"category\":\"334\",\"name\":\"Kids Tshirt\",\"gender\":\"Kids\",\"sport\":\"Cycling\",\"color\":\"Blue\",\"retailPrice\":59.0,\"sellPrice\":59.0,\"sellQuantity\":6,\"taxablePrice\":59.0,\"brand\":\"361 Sports\",\"stockQuantity\":994,\"subTotal\":354.0,\"ancesstorCategories\":[\"2426\",\"241\",\"33\",\"24\",\"2429\",\"334\",\"2439\",\"21\",\"3\",\"2\",\"1\",\"2412\",\"2503\",\"2451\"]}}

When I read this information into RDD,

```
       1.     val content = parse(event.properties.get[String]("data"))
       2.     val productID = (for {JInt(x) <- (content \\ "productID")} yield x.toString())
       3.     val sellProductQuantity = (for {JInt(x) <- (content \\ "sellQuantity")} yield x.toString())
       4.     val category = for { JArray(x) <- (content \\ "ancesstorCategories")} yield x
       5.     val compactProductId = compact(content \\ "productID")


      6.                  yield BuyEvent(
      7.                  user = userID,
      8.                  item = productID(index).toString,
      9.                  category = category(index),
      10.                count = (sellProductQuantity(index).values.toString).toInt)
```

I got an error at line 9, when processing category
I would like to get the 'ancestorCategories' of JSON into the 'category' or RDD like a list
List(2426, 2454, 241, 342, 24, 34, 2439, 21, 3, 2, 1, 2412, 2430, 2503)

Error: found   : List[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]
[ERROR] [Console$] [error]  required: Array[String]

Can anyone help me to convert from List[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] to List[String]? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Nobody can understand your code. Same mistake as in your previous post: code does not compile, code is not well formatted and indented, no imports given. Edit accordingly!

Comment: also posted at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/bqsYqN4s0So/MtIlOibqBwAJ

Answer (score 0):

you could use render to get raw String out of Value

```
scala> val json = ("name" -> "joe")
scala> compact(render(json))
res1: String = {"name":"joe"}
```

thus you could:

```
val category =
  for { JArray(x) <- (content \\ "ancesstorCategories")}
  yield compact(render(x))
```

I can not run it locally now ,hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Lucas, actually this solution is ok for me rather than the solution above. But I have another problem with this compact render. 
Now I got a list of string look like this: List(["223","2427"], ["2424","221","2453"]). I want to transfer it to List([223,2427], [2424,221,2453]), can you please help me with that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = parse(json)
var aarray = ArrayBuffer()
(content \\ "ancesstorCategories").children.foreach(x=>{
aarray+x.toString
})
var list= aarray.toList
```

I think this might works , as you can do what ever you can in the x=>{} bolock

Comment: substitute aarray+x.toString    with   aarray=x.toInt  would  solve the problem.

Comment: Dear Lucas, with this approach, I got the error"value toInt is not a member of org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue" or "value toString is not a member of org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue". Do you have any idea? Thanks.